# What method do I use to synthesize propyl-2-(2-methylpropyl)-ether and why?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I need to know which method to use to synthesize propyl-2-(2-methylpropyl)-ether.

I considered electrophilic addition of alcohols to alkenes, but I'm not really sure how the method works, and anything I found on it was hard to understand. From my understanding I need to "add" electrophilically activated alkenes to alcohol.

I don't really know what that means. I was thinking of using *t*-butanol and propylene, but the whole part of electrophilically activated alkenes threw me off. Any advice or help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Electrophilic addition simply means whatever you are adding across your alkene is electrophilic. For example, in the acid-catalyzed addition of water across an alkene, the hydronium acts as an electrophile and hence is being added to the alkene electrophillically in the rate-determining step.  The alkene is NOT the electrophile in an electrophilic addition, it is the nucleophile. This might be where you are confused.

Comment: What is "propyl-2-(2-methylpropyl)-ether" supposed to mean? It doesn't resemble any valid IUPAC name. Do maybe mean 2-methyl-1-propoxypropane?

Comment: I think what OP meant is t-Bu-O-Pr.

Comment: Thing is i think we might use different ways to write chemical names in sweden, which is where im from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two basic choices here if you are trying to do this on a lab scale. The alcohol plus alkene with catalytic acid is not an approach I would consider unless I needed a lot of this. *t*-BuOH plus acid is a recipe for isobutylene. Sodium or potassium t-butoxide is commercially available and reacted with an excess of iPr-I should give a decent yield of the ether.

The other approach is to use *t*-Butyl 2,2,2-trichloroacetimidate [compound details here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/047084289X.rb412) - a general reagent for the formation of *t*-Butyl ethers originally reported by Armstrong et al, Tet. Letts **29** 2483 (1988)